# Using ScalaCheck generators with ScalaTest's GivenWhenThen

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

I'm trying to understand what is the correct way to use `GivenWhenThen` with ScalaCheck generators. If I put the `GivenWhenThen` statements inside the `forAll` loop, the test report will print out each `GivenWhenThen` statement as many times as there are trials of that test. However, if I put them outside (i.e. all of them are immediately before the `forAll`), then the code loses the advantage that `GivenWhenThen` provides, namely of having easily readable descriptions of expected behavior immediately next to where that behavior is tested.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think `GivenWhenThen` and Property-Testing are a good fit. I think the messages that are given back from `ScalaCheck` are sufficient.

Comment: @pme Why are they a bad fit? My understanding is that `GivenWhenThen` is for BDD, and I don't see why you wouldn't wanna check the behavior of a large number of possible inputs (which is what the generators are for)

Comment: `GivenWhenThen` is a concrete step-by-step test, where as Property Testing is throwing every possible input and compare the result to a set of general properties. As mentioned that is what I think - but also your question suggesting that;)